# Syntax Error when using Arrays.asList with array shortcut declaration

Tags: java, arrays, syntax, syntax-error

Can someone explain why this expression is OK

```
TestClass[] a = {new TestClass("a")};
public List<TestClass> tall = Arrays.asList( a );
```

but this one is rejected by the compiler with a "Syntax error"

```
public List<TestClass> tall = Arrays.asList( {new TestClass("a")} );
```

Is shortcut syntax for declaring arrays only allowed on the right side of an array declaration?

Comment: Error you get: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from String[] to List<String>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the exception of an explicit array initialization (e.g., `TestClass[] a = {new TestClass("a")};`), you cannot use the `{}` notation for an array literal without calling the `new` operator.

So either explicitly call the `new` operator:

```
public List<TestClass> tall = 
    Arrays.asList( new TestClass[] {new TestClass("a")} );
```

Or better yet, use `Arrays.asList`'s varags notation, and drop the array initialization completely:

```
public List<TestClass> tall = Arrays.asList(new TestClass("a"));
```